# In Tensorflow, how to use a restored meta-graph if the meta graph was feeding with TFRecord input (without placeholders)

Tags: tensorflow

I trained a network with TFRecord input pipeline. In other words, there was no placeholders. Simple example would be:

```
input, truth = _get_next_batch()  # TFRecord. `input` is not a tf.placeholder
net = Model(input)
net.set_loss(truth)
optimizer = tf...(net.loss)
```

Let's say, I acquired three files, `ckpt-20000.meta`, `ckpt-20000.data-0000-of-0001`, `ckpt-20000.index`. I understood that, later one can import the meta-graph using the `.meta` file and access tensors such as:

```
new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('ckpt-20000.meta')
new_saver.restore(sess, 'ckpt-20000')
logits = tf.get_collection("logits")[0]
```

However, the meta-graph does not have a placeholder from the beginning in the pipeline. Is there a way that I can use meta-graph and query inference of an input?

For information, in a query application (or a script), I used to define a model with a placeholder and restored model weights (see below). I am wondering if I can just utilize the meta-graph without re-definition since it would be much more simple.

```
input = tf.placeholder(...)
net = Model(input)
tf.restore(sess, 'ckpt-2000')
lgt = sess.run(net.logits, feed_dict = {input:img})
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can build a graph that uses `placeholder_with_default()` for the inputs, so can use both `TFRecord input pipeline` as well as `feed_dict{}`.

An example:

```
input, truth = _get_next_batch()
_x = tf.placeholder_with_default(input, shape=[...], name='input')
_y = tf.placeholder_with_default(truth, shape-[...], name='label')

net = Model(_x)
net.set_loss(_y)
optimizer = tf...(net.loss)
```

Then during inference,

```
loaded_graph = tf.Graph()
with tf.Session(graph=loaded_graph) as sess:
  new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('ckpt-20000.meta')
  new_saver.restore(sess, 'ckpt-20000')

  # Get the tensors by their variable name
  input = loaded_graph.get_tensor_by_name('input:0')
  logits = loaded_graph.get_tensor_by_name(...)

  # Now you can feed the inputs to your tensors
  lgt = sess.run(logits, feed_dict = {input:img})
```

In the above example, if you don't feed input, then the input will be read from the `TFRecord input pipeline`.

Comment: Thanks, you made my day! I never knew about the `placeholder_with_default`!

Comment: @vijay m .. This is suitable when you have access to the graph you have previously coded. Is there a way to add a placeholder for a pre-trained model from Online ? How to go about this. Any idea ?

Answer (score 4):

Is there a way to do it without placeholders at test though? It should be possible to re-use the graph with a new input pipeline without resorting to slow placeholders (i.e. the test dataset may be very large). `placeholder_with_default` is a suboptimal solution in that case.

Comment: There seems to be a  way of doing this with tensorflow 1.6, as shown [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49236050/4885324).

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way is saving two meta graphs. One is for Training/Validation/Testing, and the other one is for inference.

see [Building a SavedModel](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/saved_model#building_a_savedmodel)

```
export_dir = ...
...
builder = tf.saved_model_builder.SavedModelBuilder(export_dir)
with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as sess:
  ...
  builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(sess,
                                       [tag_constants.TRAINING],
                                       signature_def_map=foo_signatures,
                                       assets_collection=foo_assets)
...
# Add a second MetaGraphDef for inference.
with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as sess:
  ...
  builder.add_meta_graph([tag_constants.SERVING])
...
builder.save()
```

The NMT tutorial also provides a detailed example about creating multiple graphs with shared variables: [Neural Machine Translation (seq2seq) Tutorial-Building Training, Eval, and Inference Graphs](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/tutorials/seq2seq#building_training_eval_and_inference_graphs)

```
train_graph = tf.Graph()
eval_graph = tf.Graph()
infer_graph = tf.Graph()

with train_graph.as_default():
  train_iterator = ...
  train_model = BuildTrainModel(train_iterator)
  initializer = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with eval_graph.as_default():
  eval_iterator = ...
  eval_model = BuildEvalModel(eval_iterator)

with infer_graph.as_default():
  infer_iterator, infer_inputs = ...
  infer_model = BuildInferenceModel(infer_iterator)

checkpoints_path = "/tmp/model/checkpoints"

train_sess = tf.Session(graph=train_graph)
eval_sess = tf.Session(graph=eval_graph)
infer_sess = tf.Session(graph=infer_graph)

train_sess.run(initializer)
train_sess.run(train_iterator.initializer)

for i in itertools.count():

  train_model.train(train_sess)

  if i % EVAL_STEPS == 0:
    checkpoint_path = train_model.saver.save(train_sess, checkpoints_path, global_step=i)
    eval_model.saver.restore(eval_sess, checkpoint_path)
    eval_sess.run(eval_iterator.initializer)
    while data_to_eval:
      eval_model.eval(eval_sess)

  if i % INFER_STEPS == 0:
    checkpoint_path = train_model.saver.save(train_sess, checkpoints_path, global_step=i)
    infer_model.saver.restore(infer_sess, checkpoint_path)
    infer_sess.run(infer_iterator.initializer, feed_dict={infer_inputs: infer_input_data})
    while data_to_infer:
      infer_model.infer(infer_sess)
```

Comment: Add details here. Else if the link is changed your answer turns invalid

Comment: @Billa Sure. I have added them.