# Restoring a Tensorflow model that uses Iterators

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have a model that's trains my network using an Iterator; following the new Dataset API pipeline model that's now recommended by Google.

I read tfrecord files, feed data to the network, train nicely, and all is going well, I save my model in the end of the training so I can run Inference on it later. A simplified version of the code is as following:

```
""" Training and saving """

training_dataset = tf.contrib.data.TFRecordDataset(training_record)
training_dataset = training_dataset.map(ds._path_records_parser)
training_dataset = training_dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
with tf.name_scope("iterators"):
  training_iterator = Iterator.from_structure(training_dataset.output_types, training_dataset.output_shapes)
  next_training_element = training_iterator.get_next()
  training_init_op = training_iterator.make_initializer(training_dataset)

def train(num_epochs):
  # compute for the number of epochs
  for e in range(1, num_epochs+1):
    session.run(training_init_op) #initializing iterator here
    while True:
      try:
        images, labels = session.run(next_training_element)
        session.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x: images, y_true: labels})
      except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
        saver_name = './saved_models/ucf-model'
        print("Finished Training Epoch {}".format(e))
        break



    """ Restoring """
# restoring the saved model and its variables
session = tf.Session()
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(r'saved_models\ucf-model.meta')
saver.restore(session, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('.\saved_models'))
graph = tf.get_default_graph()

# restoring relevant tensors/ops
accuracy = graph.get_tensor_by_name("accuracy/Mean:0") #the tensor that when evaluated returns the mean accuracy of the batch
testing_iterator = graph.get_operation_by_name("iterators/Iterator") #my iterator used in testing.
next_testing_element = graph.get_operation_by_name("iterators/IteratorGetNext") #the GetNext operator for my iterator
# loading my testing set tfrecords
testing_dataset = tf.contrib.data.TFRecordDataset(testing_record_path)
testing_dataset = testing_dataset.map(ds._path_records_parser, num_threads=4, output_buffer_size=BATCH_SIZE*20)
testing_dataset = testing_dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE)

testing_init_op = testing_iterator.make_initializer(testing_dataset) #to initialize the dataset

with tf.Session() as session:
  session.run(testing_init_op)
  while True:
    try:
      images, labels = session.run(next_testing_element)
      accuracy = session.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: test_images, y_true: test_labels}) #error here, x, y_true not defined
    except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
      break
```

My problem is mainly when I restore the model. How to feed testing data to the network?

- When I restore my Iterator using `testing_iterator = graph.get_operation_by_name("iterators/Iterator")`, `next_testing_element = graph.get_operation_by_name("iterators/IteratorGetNext")`, I get the following error:
  `GetNext() failed because the iterator has not been initialized. Ensure that you have run the initializer operation for this iterator before getting the next element.`
- So I did try to initialize my dataset using: `testing_init_op = testing_iterator.make_initializer(testing_dataset))`. I got this error: `AttributeError: 'Operation' object has no attribute 'make_initializer'`

Another issue is, since an iterator is being used, there's no need to use placeholders in the training_model, as an iterator feed data directly to the graph. But this way, how to restore my feed_dict keys in the 3rd to last line, when I feed data to the "accuracy" op?

EDIT: if someone could suggest a way to add placeholders between the Iterator and the network input, then I could try running the graph by evaluating the "accuracy" tensor while feeding data to the placeholders and ignoring the iterator altogether.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When restoring a saved meta graph, you can restore the initialization operation with name and then use it again to initialize the input pipeline for inference.

That is, when creating the graph, you can do

```
    dataset_init_op = iterator.make_initializer(dataset, name='dataset_init')
```

And then restore this operation by doing:

```
    dataset_init_op = graph.get_operation_by_name('dataset_init')
```

Here is a self contained code snippet that compares results of a randomly initialized model before and after restoring.

### Saving an Iterator

```
np.random.seed(42)
data = np.random.random([4, 4])
X = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[4, 4], name='X')
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(X)
iterator = tf.data.Iterator.from_structure(dataset.output_types, dataset.output_shapes)
dataset_next_op = iterator.get_next()

# name the operation
dataset_init_op = iterator.make_initializer(dataset, name='dataset_init')

w = np.random.random([1, 4])
W = tf.Variable(w, name='W', dtype=tf.float32)
output = tf.multiply(W, dataset_next_op, name='output')     
sess = tf.Session()
saver = tf.train.Saver()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
sess.run(dataset_init_op, feed_dict={X:data})
while True:
    try:
        print(sess.run(output))
    except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
        saver.save(sess, 'tmp/', global_step=1002)
    break
```

And then you can restore the same model for inference as follows:

### Restoring saved iterator

```
np.random.seed(42)
data = np.random.random([4, 4])
tf.reset_default_graph()
sess = tf.Session()
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('tmp/-1002.meta')
ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(os.path.dirname('tmp/checkpoint'))
saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
graph = tf.get_default_graph()

# Restore the init operation
dataset_init_op = graph.get_operation_by_name('dataset_init')

X = graph.get_tensor_by_name('X:0')
output = graph.get_tensor_by_name('output:0')
sess.run(dataset_init_op, feed_dict={X:data})
while True:
try:
    print(sess.run(output))
except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
    break
```

Comment: This is helpful. Is it possible to reinitialize the iterator with a new dataset?

It seems that what I really want to do is save the reinitializable iterator itself (not `dataset_init_op`). Then I want to restore that iterator and create a new initializer with a new dataset. But TF complains when I try to save the Iterator op.

Comment: @masonk I'm not sure what you are trying to say. If you are talking about initializing the same `dataset` pipeline with different data that have the same structure (train set vs test set for instance), then it is just a matter of running the `dataset_init_op` with the new data as an argument to `feed_dict` as shown above. This is initializing the reinitializable iterator with the new data. If the input data is of different structure though, you need to look at [feedable iterator](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets).

Comment: I filed this bug on tensorflow/tensorflow today which describes my use-case: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/20098

In the end I did use a feedable iterator. I think feeding the placeholder variables as you're doing is only good if your dset is in memory. I wanted to reinitialize a reinitializable iterator from a new Dataset.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest to use [`tf.contrib.data.make_saveable_from_iterator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/data/make_saveable_from_iterator), which has been designed precisely for this purpose. It is much less verbose and does not require you to change existing code, in particular how you define your iterator.

Working example, when we save everything after step 5 has completed. Note how I don't even bother knowing what seed is used.

```
import tensorflow as tf

iterator = (
  tf.data.Dataset.range(100)
  .shuffle(10)
  .make_one_shot_iterator())
batch = iterator.get_next(name='batch')

saveable_obj = tf.contrib.data.make_saveable_from_iterator(iterator)
tf.add_to_collection(tf.GraphKeys.SAVEABLE_OBJECTS, saveable_obj)
saver = tf.train.Saver()

with tf.Session() as sess:
  tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
  for step in range(10):
    print('{}: {}'.format(step, sess.run(batch)))
    if step == 5:
      saver.save(sess, './foo', global_step=step)

# 0: 1
# 1: 6
# 2: 7
# 3: 3
# 4: 8
# 5: 10
# 6: 12
# 7: 14
# 8: 5
# 9: 17
```

Then later, if we resume from step 6, we get the same output.

```
import tensorflow as tf

saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('./foo-5.meta')
with tf.Session() as sess:
  saver.restore(sess, './foo-5')
  for step in range(6, 10):
    print('{}: {}'.format(step, sess.run('batch:0')))
# 6: 12
# 7: 14
# 8: 5
# 9: 17
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't solve the problem related to initializing the iterator, but since I pre-process my dataset using [map](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/data/Dataset#map) method, and I apply transformations defined by Python operations wrapped with [py_func](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_func), which cannot be serialized for storing\restoring, I'll have to initialize my dataset when I want to restore it anyway.

So, the problem that remains is how to feed data to my graph when I restore it. I placed a tf.identity node between the iterator output and my network input. Upon restoring, I feed my data to the identity node. A **better solution** that I discovered later is using `placeholder_with_default()`, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44769126/in-tensorflow-how-to-use-a-restored-meta-graph-if-the-meta-graph-was-feeding-wi).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest having a look at CheckpointInputPipelineHook [CheckpointInputPipelineHook](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/CheckpointInputPipelineHook), which implements saving iterator state for further training with tf.Estimator.