# How to restore tf.data.Dataset position (state) in TensorFlow 2

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow2.0

I'm training a model on a [tf.data.Dataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset).  I'm using a machine without uptime guarantees.  When I get interruptions, I want to be able to resume training from where it left off.  In particular, I want to make sure I'm using the identical sequence of minibatches regardless of whether I get interruptions.

In TensorFlow 1.x, one can do this by creating an iterator over a Dataset and saving/restoring a SaveableObject returned by [tf.data.experimental.make_saveable_from_iterator(iterator)](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/make_saveable_from_iterator):

- [Restoring a Tensorflow model that uses Iterators - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52322033/12323519)

In TensorFlow 2.0.0, I can't seem to make that work:

```
import tensorflow as tf
ds = tf.data.Dataset.range(10)
tf.data.experimental.make_saveable_from_iterator(iter(ds))
# ==>
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "dataset.py", line 3, in <module>
#     tf.data.experimental.make_saveable_from_iterator(iter(ds))
#   File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/data/experimental/ops/iterator_ops.py", line 72, in make_saveable_from_iterator
#     return _Saveable(iterator._iterator_resource)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
#   File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/data/experimental/ops/iterator_ops.py", line 82, in __init__
#     iterator_resource.name + "-state")
#   File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py", line 1090, in name
#     "Tensor.name is meaningless when eager execution is enabled.")
# AttributeError: Tensor.name is meaningless when eager execution is enabled.
```

Is there a way to do this in TensorFlow 2?