# How to inference with a single example in tensorflow with dataset pipeline

Tags: python, tensorflow, dataset, recurrent-neural-network, inference

i train dnn's with variable length input vectors. Therefore i created a dataset pipeline with TFRecord files and feature_lists. This is working.
normally i'm using the feed_dict{...} to get the "answer" for a single example. With the variable input this is now very hard to realize. So i'm wondering if there is a nice way to feed the dataset pipeline with a single example without using:

```
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(data_path)
```

but instead using something different where i can put a single example in it and then process the prediction with my normal (and working) dataset-pipeline.

a workarround would be to save the single example to a TFRecord file and then read this data from a file. But I think there is a different way to do this?!

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tf.placeholder_with_default` and as default you pass the `iterator.get_next()` results. For more information see this post: [assign iterator.get_next() as default for placeholder with default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44769126/in-tensorflow-how-to-use-a-restored-meta-graph-if-the-meta-graph-was-feeding-wi)